# Issues with converting Hex NCRs to emojis Swift

Tags: swift

How can I convert this type of  hex string

> &#x1F697;

to emoji, and vice versa?

I have tried to use this, but its returns same string

```
func decode(_ s: String) -> String? {
    let data = s.data(using: .utf8)!
    return String(data: data, encoding: .nonLossyASCII)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(I am force unwrapping for the sake of simplicity, since the specified emoji hex is valid)

```
let hexStr = String("&#x1F697;".dropFirst(3).dropLast())
let emoji = String(UnicodeScalar(Int(hexStr, radix: 16)!)!)
```

Comment: thanks, and what about this type of hex
"&#x231b;&#xfe0f;"
there are emojis which are combine of multiple emojis, how should I use it?